# Leer valor dentro de un JSON que devuelve un API

Tags: php, json

Como respuesta de un consumo a un API me llega un JSON que decodifico de la siguiente manera:

```
$json_document_object = json_decode($response_doc);
```

Y el resultado es:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"number":["number tiene que estar entre 990000000 - 995000000 o no se estableció el atributo que define el minimo y maximo."]}}
```

Lo que necesito es obtener el valor de los errores, pero no me da resultado. Una de las formas que he intentado es:

```
$json_document_object->errors->number
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de cada uno de los elementos?

Comment: Que resultado te devuelve el `$json_document_object->errors`?

Comment: ´Trying to get property of non-object´

Comment: Si te da ese error, es porque hay mala conversion del json. Revisa el mensaje que te da json_last_error_msg para ver si te da más info.

Comment: Hola @JuanCarlos, ¿solucionaste el problema? ¿te funciona correctamente o te sigue fallando? Si tienes alguna duda o sigue sin funcionar déjanos un comentario.

Comment: Si @OscarGarcia, esa solución funciona para este caso donde sabemos que es lo que vamos a analizar, pero me he dado cuenta que el archivo que llega no siempre es el mismo, siempre va a ser Json pero con diferentes elementos, es posible saber en que posición llega el elemento message?

Comment: Todo es posible, pero necesito más ejemplos de resultados. ¿Puedes proporcionar otro ejemplo en el que cambie dónde está el mensaje? Normalmente un servicio REST siempre devolverá un tipo de resultado. ¿Es el mismo servicio u otro diferente?

Comment: ¿Te funcionó mi respuesta? Si tienes una nueva duda que difiere de ésta, o que es una ampliación o continuación, sería recomendable abrir una nueva pregunta para solucionarlo. Si consideras que está relacionada la nueva pregunta que me planteaste en los comentarios, entonces te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y agregues a ella los nuevos datos o las nuevas dudas (y que nos dejes un comentario en la respuesta para indicar que lo has hecho).

Answer (score 4):

Si te fijas, el contenido de `number` es una matriz de valores:

```
"number": [ ... ]
```

Por lo que deberás indicar un índice, por ejemplo el `0`:

```
$json_document_object->errors->number[0]
```

---

Un ejemplo del código obteniendo únicamente el primer elemento (índice `0`):

```
<?php
$response_doc = '{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"number":["number tiene que estar entre 990000000 - 995000000 o no se estableció el atributo que define el minimo y maximo."]}}';
$json_document_object = json_decode($response_doc);
if ($json_document_object === null) {
  die('Error decodificando JSON');
}
echo 'Mensaje:', PHP_EOL, $json_document_object->errors->number[0], PHP_EOL;
```

[Pulse aquí para ver el resultado de la ejecución en línea.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VSoWusppZ7UK4Q92)

---

Un ejemplo del código enumerando cada uno de los mensajes contenidos en `number`:

```
<?php
$response_doc = '{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"number":["number tiene que estar entre 990000000 - 995000000 o no se estableció el atributo que define el minimo y maximo."]}}';
$json_document_object = json_decode($response_doc);
if ($json_document_object === null) {
  die('Error decodificando JSON');
}
foreach ($json_document_object->errors->number as $numero => $mensaje) {
    echo 'Mensaje número ', $numero, ':', PHP_EOL, $mensaje, PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Pulse aquí para ver el resultado de la ejecución en línea.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tcq5MeU9UXzwL779)